# webdriver-manager update command not working in protractor

Tags: selenium-webdriver, npm, protractor

From today morning I am facing an issue while using the command `webdriver-manager update`. After doing npm install,when I run `webdriver-manager update` it is giving me the below error

```
/Users/sudharsan/dev/unifing/services/data-integration/unifi_www/datai/static/angular/test/e2e/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/webdriver-manager/built/lib/cli/logger.js:66
info(...msgs) {
     ^^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token ...
at exports.runInThisContext (vm.js:53:16)
at Module._compile (module.js:373:25)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:416:10)
at Module.load (module.js:343:32)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:300:12)
at Module.require (module.js:353:17)
at require (internal/module.js:12:17)
at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/sudharsan/dev/unifing/services/data-integration/unifi_www/datai/static/angular/test/e2e/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/webdriver-manager/built/lib/cli/index.js:8:10)
at Module._compile (module.js:409:26)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:416:10)
```

The above issue occurs in both Mac OS and in Debian.

protractor version im using is `4.0.9`

Comment: I'm seeing the same issue here on our CI server (protractor 4.0.11, node 4.3.2, npm 3.8.6) but it works find on my desktop.

Comment: is it working fine even if you delete and re-install the protractor? @NicholasAlbion

Comment: Locally I'm using webdriver-manager 10.2.4, but our CI server is using 10.2.9

run  `grep version /Users/sudharsan/dev/unifing/services/data-integration/unifi_www/datai/static/angular/test/e2e/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/webdriver-manager/package.json` to check your version

Comment: Even my machine has the same version `10.2.9`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

An issue has been raised on GitHub: https://github.com/angular/webdriver-manager/issues/170

Comment: After updating node js to v6 solved the problem.Thanks for your answer!! @Nicholas Albion

Comment: @SudharsanSelvaraj please consider accepting the answer :)

Answer (score 2):

Protractor 5 relies on node version 6.9.4 or higher so the issue is most likely your node version. You can either upgrade that or install an older version of protractor:

`npm install -g protractor@4.0.13`

Answer (score 1):

It's an issue with node v4.x.x, update to node v6.x.x and it should work.